# Link Scrolling Between Two Tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I have two same-sized tables on the same page.
How can I link the scrolling between them so that when I scroll to the right at the top it also scrolls to the right at the bottom etc?

http://plnkr.co/edit/tXpr9hRGTDUEnrjEwr7w

```
<div class="scroll-left">
  <div id="example1"></div>
</div>
<div class="scroll-right">
  <div id="example2"></div>
</div>

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

function getData() {
  var data = [
    [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],
    [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],
    [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],
    [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],
    [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
  ];
  return data;
}

var example1 = document.getElementById('example1');
var example2 = document.getElementById('example2');

var hot1 = new Handsontable(example1, {
  data: getData(),
  rowHeaders: true,
  colHeaders: true,
});

var hot2 = new Handsontable(example2, {
  data: getData(),
  rowHeaders: true,
  colHeaders: true,
});



});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this code to the end of yours to link the scrolling from the top table to the bottom table:

```
var $eg1holder = $(example1).find('.wtHolder');
var $eg2holder = $(example2).find('.wtHolder');

$eg1holder.scroll(function() {
  var x = $(this).scrollTop();
  var y = $(this).scrollLeft();
  $eg2holder.scrollTop(x).scrollLeft(y);
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/vCn8Fru5SWTT6Sn99p33

Comment: Double upvotes if I could! This is JQuery https://api.jquery.com/scroll/ and https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/ etc right? I see lots more divs now I inspect it. How did you know to chose .wtHolder? Trial and error?

Comment: Yup. Took me a bit to figure that out.